# SharePoint 2010 Deploying Farm Web Part loses reference to projects in solution

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, reference, web-parts

I have a SharePoint Visual Studio project (SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2012) that deploys as a Farm solution, not Sandboxed.  There are a couple of other class libraries in the solution that have a strong name and are included in the package under the Advanced tab.  The project builds fine.  However, when I deploy it, the using references to the other dll's break and the deploy fails.

Here's the wierd part: it is only breaking in one of the class libraries.

I have the following projects in my solution: 
* MyProject.View (the SharePoint project with visual web parts)
* MyProject.Presenter (this is the one that's breaking)
* MyProject.Data
* MyProject.Model

I set up a sample web part that used the MyProject.Model class library and all was well.  But when the .View project references the .Presenter library, the .Presenter library loses references to .Model and .Data.

Does anyone have an idea on what I should check?

Comment: Figured it out.  Two part issue.  First, the custom DLL's needed [assembly:AllowPartiallytrustedCallers()] added to it (can be found in System.Security).  Second, needed to switch from a sandboxed to a farm deployed web part.  Sandboxed web parts are very particular about which items in the GAC can be accessed.